# Chrome extension chrome.webRequest API - Some http request headers not coming in request headers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I was working on chrome extension with motive of intercepting all HTTP(S) requests/responses and log all headers into persistent file (on disk). I was almost close to my goal. But when I looked some requests closely, I found that in many requests "`If-None-Match`" and "`If-Modified-Since`" are missing in `requestHeaders`. Though, I can see them in Network panel displayed by the Developer Tools.

I tried hard to figure out any patterns, causing such behavior. But, unfortunately there is no such pattern.

Anybody please help.

Answer (score 1):

The receive the list of requestHeader is necessary to use the `onBeforeSendHeaders` event from [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

In the `onBeforeSendHeaders` description is [mentioned](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote) that some headers are not available for reading/processing:

- Authorization
- Cache-Control
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Host
- If-Modified-Since
- If-None-Match
- If-Range
- Partial-Data
- Pragma
- Proxy-Authorization
- Proxy-Connection
- Transfer-Encoding

I'm afraid you will not be able to read or modify these headers, because it's an API forced limitation.

Comment: Due to constraints you mentioned in your answer, with `onBeforeSendHeaders` event, I used `onSendHeaders` event and in many requests I get `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` header, but not in all requests

Comment: The problem is that on onSendHeaders you may only read these, but not modify. But you need to log them only, so it will work.

Comment: yes, I don't want to modify. I just want to log(persistently) each request in order to perform simulation on logs.

Comment: @SalmanPatel `onSendHeaders` is the only way to access these headers.

Comment: that I already tried and its creating problems as I said earlier